# Obtaining different results with the same parameters

Tags: ros-noetic, base-local-planner, base-global-planner, avoid-obstacle

There's something weird about the algorithm I use in my robot:

In the planner algorithm I use, I can send my robot to a point on an existing map and bring it to the starting point from that point. And when I operate it this way, my robot can perform its task beautifully and without hitting obstacles. However, when I send it to the same target point on the 2nd or 3rd run and bring it back to the starting point without making any changes to the parameters or elsewhere, collisions with obstacles occur. Unfortunately, there is no stable situation in this regard. I can't understand this strange situation. I wonder why this is happening?

Comment: There's a lot of missing detail here, and so it will be difficult for anyone to help you answer this. Are you using Nav2? What planner? What configuration? etc.